# Required Header authorization is missing. Ensure a valid Authorization token is passed in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

messageToCosmos function is working in my dummy project but not here; I am getting

> { *Error: Required Header authorization is missing. Ensure a valid
>   Authorization token is passed. ActivityId:
>   1250064f-f72d-4b73-adb7-4f2bcd91e778,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0*

Please find messageToCosmos function, you can give it a try i have given my key and end point

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv').config();
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
const app = express();
const dbString = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/blue-isSecure';
const messageRoute = require('./routes/messages')
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
// const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const cors = require('cors')
const cron = require('node-cron')



// cosmos
const CosmosClient = require('@azure/cosmos').CosmosClient;
const config = require('./config')

const endpoint = config.endpoint;
const cosmosKey = config.key;
const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, cosmosKey });

const databaseId = config.database.id
const containerId = config.container.containerMessages




const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req, file, cb ) =>{
        cb(null,'files')
    },
    filename:(req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})
// app.use(cors)
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
 app.use(multer({storage:multer.memoryStorage()}).single('file'))

// app.use(fileUpload({
//     useTempFiles:true
// }))

app.use('/files', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'files')))
app.use('/blue-isSecure',messageRoute)

async function messageToCosmos(itemBody) {
    const { item } = await client.database(databaseId).container(containerId).items.upsert(itemBody);
    console.log(`Created family item with id:\n${itemBody.id}\n`);
  };

  messageToCosmos({message:'hey buddy'}).catch(err =>console.log(err))

mongoose.connect(dbString,{useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true})
    .then(connect =>{
        app.listen(process.env.PORT || 2020)
        console.log('listening')
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

> My Config file

```
var config = {}

config.endpoint = "https://bluecosmosdb.documents.azure.com:443/";

config.key = "j2EFBfUe1GQpd5Sewv0LXUUluhrjdOuQ0w14JkJYSe4ISVkN9SBBPxq8wynW6bs7QCicbYsB6DaAfVd5Q1K6Nw==";


config.database = {
    id: 'blueSecures'
  }

  config.container = {
    containerMessages: 'messages'
  }

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: You can't use the Cosmos Node.js SDK to access a MongoDB database. You need to use a Mongo client and pass the correct endpoint which you can get from the Azure portal.

Comment: According to my understanding, you use Azure Cosmos DB sql API but you cannot connect it. Is that right? Besides, could you please tell me the version of the SDK ```@azure/cosmos``` you use?

Answer (score 1):

**It worked for me:**

Uninstall @azure/cosmos and reinstall it using the 2.1.7 version (**npm install @azure/cosmos@2.1.7 --save**)

[refrence link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35948#issue-473448440)(thanks to @kilmfer91)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the OPs code is that they renamed the "key" variable to "cosmosKey". To fix it:

```
const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key: cosmosKey });
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding body-parser with `extended: true` retrieved authorization header on my node.js server code

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```